# How to write native code in ASM

Tags: java, java-native-interface, java-bytecode-asm

I am an avid ASM writer. I am attempting to write native java code in asm.
The issue I am experiencing is that parameters passed from Java do not appear to be receive by the asm code. C++ code appears to receive the paramters using the windows 64 bit calling convention, ie rcx,rdx,r8,r9,stack, and initially I presumed it would be the same for asm but it does not seem to be so. I have spent quite some time searching for possible explainations and examples but have yet to find any so I thought I would ask. I will very much appreaciate some assistence in identifying where I am going wrong. Thank you very much. Below are code snipets explaining what I have developed so far...

In NativeInterface.java

```
public native static String test(int _number);
```

In Calling.java

```
String s=NativeInterface.test(123);
```

In NativeJava.asm

```
.data
dString     db  "This is my string",0
.code
java_test PROC _iNumber:QWORD
 invoke dialog_showMessageInteger,"ASM CODE","Number=",_iNumber
 mov rax,rv(java_createStringUTF8,JNIenv,ADDR dString)
 ret
java_test ENDP
```

The dialog opened in asm does not show "123" but instead "1918844240"
The above code passes the string to java successfully.

It seems I can successfuly pass parameters to java from asm.
At this point I cannot pass parameters to asm from java.

I was hoping the standard windows 64 bit calling convention would be used but doesn't seem that way. I cannot find any documentation anywhere. Can someone please explain what I should expect in asm.
Many, many Thanks.

Comment: I've used assembler back in the last century (Z80 processor, year 1981). May I ask you, what are the benefits of using asm nowadays? Curiosity? Speed? Abstract coding (if this is a case, just write an emulator for basic Turing machine)?

Comment: @zlakad: Sure, speed is one possible reason.  *If* you know exactly what you're doing, you can often beat C++ compilers for some loops.  If you don't, you can easily make slower code.  [Why is this C++ code faster than my hand-written assembly for testing the Collatz conjecture?](//stackoverflow.com/q/40354978)

Comment: @zlakad Crunching is always faster in machine code. It is the ultimate optimisation for any application. However, it is processor dependent.

Comment: @Peter Cordes Yes, C++ does come with built in optimisations but it seems very clunky as a language.

Comment: If you use C++ carefully, you can usually get gcc or clang `-O3 -march=native` to produce nearly-optimal asm even for small functions.  e.g. [What is the efficient way to count set bits at a position or lower?](//stackoverflow.com/q/34407437).  It's very rarely worth the portability downside to actually write asm by hand, rather than just tweaking the C++ source to hand-hold the compiler when its asm output isn't optimal.  Over a larger scale, compilers can do more inlining and constant propagation than you can do by hand in maintainable asm code.

Comment: @PeterCordes, C++ is the ultimate choice for (as much as possible fast) and also so-called independent of processor - architecture environment. But, even C++ has *frameworks*. Assembler is independent of frameworks, **but** the programmer have to rebuild the code for **every** possible target... Am I wrong?

Comment: @PenelopeHubble, You cannot anticipate **every** environment (processor) for your program (even not for piece of program)!

Comment: @zlakad: Yeah, that's pretty accurate.  Except IDK what you mean by "frameworks".  Instead of recompiling with `-march=znver1` to optimize for Ryzen, or `-march=skylake-avx512`, you have to manually optimize everything.  And of course if you want a version for the Windows calling convention instead of Linux, you have to change your code manually.  Or totally rewrite it for AArch64 instead of x86-64.

Comment: @zlakad: Of course you can't anticipate every possible environment for your program.  Lots of code runs in known environments, e.g. on Intel x86-64 CPUs on servers.  It's not rare that it makes sense to put significant effort into tuning for one specific microarchitecture, which is even more specific than just writing in asm for x86-64.  (I wouldn't actually *recommend* writing by hand in asm, but if you've read http://agner.org/optimize/ carefully, then sure if you want). It's not like C++ is infinitely portable either, and you still have to build for all targets you care about ahead of time.

Comment: @zlakad: I also wouldn't recommend writing in asm without having a C++ version first, that you can use as a baseline for benchmarks, and to check against for correctness for different possible inputs.  Compiler-generated asm is often a good starting point for optimization, unless it did a horrible job.

Comment: @PenelopeHubble: To answer your question: Have you looked at compiler output from C++ that uses the JNI headers / libraries?  I'd expect it uses the normal Windows calling convention for passing primitive types by value, but maybe they're "boxed" somehow or more likely there's a hidden first arg.   (Also, you have a potential bug: you declared the function as taking an `int` in Java, but a QWORD in asm.  The calling convention allows passing a 32-bit integer with garbage in the high bits of a 64-bit register.  At least x86-64 SysV does; I haven't checked Windows.)

Comment: Oh, guys I'm totally agree with you! I'm just a hobby programmer, and I KNOW what you're implicated! I wish you good luck!

Comment: @PenelopeHubble C++ seems to me so far most elegant programming language when you also need to care about performance and to control final code for particular architecture/target. It's IMO lot more powerful and elegant than Java, for example, but with Java you even don't get good performance, so C++ is win-win. But there are some high level languages suited better for certain tasks, especially if you don't care about performance too much. IMO the biggest hurdle in effective C++ usage is, that it takes lot of time and experience to write good C++ source, and it's super easy to write bad code...

Comment: @Peter Cordes I am surprised you didn't trim the QWORD down to a DWORD to see it is not the value of 123. I believe disassemnling C++ code is the last option. I point here is hoping to find someone who can say, been there, done that, this is what you need to know... Many Thanks for your contributions :)

Comment: @PenelopeHubble: I *did* look at the integer value, and notice that it did fit into 32 bits so the upper 32 were zero, so that *potential* bug wasn't the cause of the problem in this case.  It looked like it might be a pointer, which is what got me thinking of boxed args or "hidden" first args.  Didn't have room to explain the thought process in my earlier comment, and I hardly ever do anything with Java, just C/C++ and asm so I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Peter Cordes who suggested that there might be some hidden parameters that are passed and to disassemble some C++ code for find out for sure.

I didn't need to go that far. I had already been looking at come C++ code and I noticed that all of the native routines had JNIenv and jclass as the first two parameters.

I altered my code to read...

```
java_test PROC _JNIenv:QWORD,_jclass:QWORD,_iNumber:QWORD
```

and the value of 123 was indeed given successfully.

It is a guess that the first two paramters are the JNIenv and the calling class but considering it is how the C++ functions are formed I think that is a pretty good guess.

Thanks for your help and support.
Regards
Penny
Take Care

Comment: wait, you didn't study the JNI specs before writing first code? Oh, you should... you definitely should. It's such a joy, it basically blends everything what is wrong about Java with everything what is wrong about C and C++, and forbids all the good parts, so whenever I'm writing the JNI wrapper part of my C++ libraries, it feels like torture. Would I had to write that part in asm, it would be like squared torture (and I love assembly, it's the Java and JNI killing it... that, and my need to support 3 different CPUs, so using asm makes no sense for me, the JNI part is already annoying enough).

Answer (score 1):

To use JNI:

1. Write a `native` method in a class.
2. Compile the class.
3. Use javah (or in Java 10, javac) to generate a C/C++ header file.
4. In the language of your choice, implement the functions for the generated signatures, the same way as C or C++ would with the headers and libraries provided by the Java vendor. Be sure to export the function names verbatim.

When you need to make Java call:

1. Use javap -s to find the appropriate Java signature and type descriptions.
2. Pick a JNI calling function, depending on the way you which to pass parameters, and the type of method you are calling.